# Query ObjectId of ConditionalAccessLocationCondition

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am writing a script to write to Azure, I basically want to find a user, create a network location, create a conditional access policy. This is what I have so far. The trouble is that the $secmon_guid and $location_policy_guid do not work. If I manually put the values in, it works.

```
# Run these commands first to connect and install without the #

Install-Module -Name AzureAD -AllowClobber -Force # Answer Y to install NuGet. Run once on workstation running script.
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns -Force # Install this to allow us to setup a trusted location. Run once on workstation running script.
Install-Module MSOnline -Force #Allow us to edit users. Run once on workstation running script.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine #Set execution policy to allow our script to do things.
Import-Module -Name AzureAD #The following 3 commands are ran for each client.
Connect-AzureAD # Use GA credentials from Glue
Connect-MsolService #Reauthenticate if necessary.
Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy #This will list out all of the existing CA policies. This is a good opportunity to get them into documentation.
Connect-MgGraph #This enabled graph, you will need to approve the request in the popup window.

#Set variable for account name
Set-Variable -name "account" -Value "secmon"


#Create named location for the IP address
$ipRanges = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.IpRange
$ipRanges.cidrAddress = "IP ADDR"
New-AzureADMSNamedLocationPolicy -OdataType "#microsoft.graph.ipNamedLocation" -DisplayName "Blackpoint IP Address for SecMon" -IsTrusted $true -IpRanges $ipRanges

#Disable MFA for secmon
Get-MsolUser -SearchString "secmon" | Set-MsolUser -StrongAuthenticationRequirements @()
#Get the Azure AD GUID for use later
$secmon_guid = Get-MsolUser -SearchString "secmon" | Select ObjectID
#Name the policy
$name = "Allow Secmon Only from Blackpoint IP"
#Enable the policy. Set to Disabled to test.
$state = "Enabled"
#Get location GUID and save to variable
$location_policy_guid = Get-AzureADMSNamedLocationPolicy | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -Contains 'Blackpoint IP Address for SecMon' | Select-Object -Property Id
#Working on this

#Create the overarching condition set for CA, this is the container.
$conditions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessConditionSet
#Include all applications - This might be able to be removed?
$conditions.Applications = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessApplicationCondition
$conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = 'All'
#Create the user condition and include secmon
$conditions.Users = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessUserCondition
$conditions.Users.IncludeUsers = $secmon_guid
#Add new location policy to CA policy
$conditions.Locations = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessLocationCondition
$conditions.Locations.IncludeLocations = $location_policy_guid
#Grant access control to CA policy
$controls = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessGrantControls
$controls._Operator = "OR"
$controls.BuiltInControls = "block"

#End work
 
New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy `
    -DisplayName $name `
    -State $state `
    -Conditions $conditions `
    -GrantControls $controls
```

The error I get is due to poorly formatted GUID's, the values I am pulling are not correct. How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy
Code: BadRequest
Message: 1054: Invalid location value: @{Id=1234GUID}.
InnerError:
  RequestId: 5678GUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you define the variables, you need to use -ExpandProperty on the select-object statement e.g:

```
$secmon_guid = Get-MsolUser -SearchString "secmon" | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectID
```

Otherwise, you would have to access your current variable like so:

```
$conditions.Users.IncludeUsers = $secmon_guid.ObjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the location in a variable, I used the below in the AzureAD module:

```
$AllowedCountriesObjectId = Get-AzureADMSNamedLocationPolicy | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -Contains "Allowed Countries" | Select Id
```